# Apply All Transforms moves objects away from their location or warps their shape

Tags: modeling, transforms

I am working on a character model and have everything parented together. I've been told that to prevent problems later on in modeling that we should be trying to select all parts of the model and apply all transforms. This is the before and after of applying all transforms and then all locations:

Before Apply Location[image]
After Apply Location[image]
After Apply All Transforms[image]

Apply All Location seems to warp the shape of the flower petals and apply all transforms moves their location. Can anyone tell me what is going on here? Do I even need to apply all transforms?

[image]

Comment: I think we'd need to know the stack of influences, here.. (object-level transforms, parenting, modifiers, other constraints) to give an accurate answer. Perhaps share your file on https://blend-exchange.com/ for someone to help you out?

Comment: As @RobinBetts mentions, without knowing which influences there are on the mesh, it's hard to tell what exactly is going on. Just a general information: let's assume you have a simple object without any modifiers etc., applying rotation and scale usually doesn't change the appearance and **origin** of an object. Say you move a cube with its origin at the center of the mesh to X = 3, then scale and rotate it. If you now apply rotation and scale, the mesh stays where it is, but rotations will be set to 0° and scale to 1.

Comment: But it is still at X = 3, and rotating and scaling it again will do these transformations around the origin at X = 3. However, when you apply the location, this will reset the location to the world origin at X = Y = Z = 0 **without moving the mesh**. So it is not like Alt+G, clearing the location i.e. moving origin **and** mesh to 0,0,0. If you now do a different transformation like rotating or scaling, it looks as if it is no longer doing this from its center, because the origin has now been moved away from the center of the mesh. And so this might cause problems with added modifiers, too.

Comment: What you already can see in your screenshots is that before applying the location, each object has its origin more or less in the center of its geometry. After applying location, you can only see the origin(s) in the world center. So if some transformations/modifiers etc. rely on the relative location of the object, it doesn't work anymore as expected.

Comment: If I understand this correctly what is the way to check the "stack of influences" on each piece of my object? I add the .Blend file to my post. I did not know that I could do that.

Answer (score -1):

This trouble may appear in the case you have some deforming modifiers active. If your actual model is ready just try to apply them and after that apply all transforms.

Comment: I did try this method and it still came out warped like in the pictures.

Answer (score -2):

Also check if you have any keyframes in your dope sheet, animated models tend to jump when transforms are applied